# Scrolling through list using selenium Python till end

Tags: python, facebook, selenium, web-scraping, scrollview

I'm trying to scroll through my facebook friendlist / chatlist using `selenium webdriver` via python but it only scrolls web page and not that list.

I tried something like this:

```
list = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('xpath')
hover = ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(list)
hover.perform()
```

But nothing happened!

Can anyone please share how it can be done.

Comment: Your `list` is not an element but list of elements - you should not pass it to `move_to_element`. Also it's bad idea to use `list` as variable name

Comment: you do know that scraping is not allowed on facebook, right?

Comment: @luschn Facebook or any other platform won't stop you from learning technology, specially when you can do same thing by copy paste but I'm just trying to automate it. Hope it doesn't qualify as being against TOS.

Comment: Scrapping [_Facebook_](https://www.facebook.com/) is against the [_ToS_](https://www.facebook.com/legal/terms) and you are liable to be questioned and may even land up in [_Facebook Jail_](https://www.facebook.com/help/community/question/?id=804287426255468). Use _Facebook API_ instead.

Comment: you can learn a lot of stuff without breaking the rules, you know ;)

Comment: Haha..True that..

Comment: That's why tried that function on normal websites :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a for loop.

Say:

```
for element in list:
    hover = ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(element)

    hover.perform()
```